# Adding NPM javascript library to Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, laravel-8

I'm using the [mobiscroll](https://mobiscroll.com/) javascript component library with a new Laravel 8 app I'm building. I've used the trial scripts by simply copying the minified css / js to the `public/css` and `public/js` directories of my laravel app, and then pushing the script / css files into the layout's `stack`.

I'd like to be able to require these more "natively" by installing the module via npm and referencing the module. In a react app I'd have no problem with this-- but how is it done in laravel?

I've tried adding `window.mobiscroll = require('@mobiscroll/javascript');` to the `bootstrap.js` file, since that seems to be how the `axios` and `_` libraries are being made available, but I still am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: mobiscroll is not defined` errors when I try to initialize a component.

I also tried adding it to the `app.js` file like this:

```
require('alpinejs');
require('@mobiscroll/javascript');
```

with the same error as before. I am running `npm run watch` so the `mix` process is happening and succeeding with each attempt, so I don't think it's simply a problem with caching or compilation.

I didn't see anything that seemed to address this on SO or the laravel docs.

EDIT: having the same issue with `dayjs`, added via `npm i dayjs`, added to `bootstrap.js` using `window.dayjs = require('dayjs');`, compiled via mix, cleared all caches, and still getting error `dayjs is not defined`.

Comment: you need to make a difference conceptionally between libraries that are used by node and libraries that are packaged so that they are served as statics for your frontend. It seems like you are requiring those libs such that your project thinks they are only for nodes build process but not for the client. You need to check out how to package third party dependencies.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#vanilla-js. Do you call the `mix` method ?

Answer (score 2):

First, install Mobiscroll in your root Laravel folder.

```
npm install @mobiscroll/javascript-lite --save-dev
```

Then you want to reference the JS and CSS in the appropriate spots.

In resources/js/bootstrap.js.

```
try {
    window.mobiscroll = require('@mobiscroll/javascript-lite');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {
}
```

In resources/css/app.css.

```
@import '~@mobiscroll/javascript-lite/dist/css/mobiscroll.css';
```

If your webpack.mix.js is something like this...

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

Do an `npm run prod`.

Make sure you reference your generated CSS file in your Blade template/layout.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

Also, for JS.

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks you @karl-hill for the explanation and info!